# Mysql: how to add a virtual column before UNION

Tags: mysql

I want to add a virtual column `'enabled' = 1` for all the result from the first union of my statement, and the `'enabled' = 0` for the next union. This is the statement I have so far...

```
SELECT p.*
FROM member_permissions mp
JOIN permissions p ON p.permission_id = mp.permission_id
WHERE member_id = 1
UNION
SELECT pgp
FROM member_permissions mp
JOIN permission_link pl ON pl.permission_group_id = mp.permission_group_id
JOIN permissions pgp ON pgp.permission_id = pl.permission_id
WHERE member_id = 1
UNION        // this will have enabled = 0 //    
SELECT *
FROM permissions
```

Comment: For optimization purposes, check if you can use UNION ALL instead of UNION. UNION needs to do duplicate checks, the ALL variant does not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just specify the new column as the source:

```
select column1, column2, ..., 1 as enabled
from ....
union
select column1, column2, ..., 0 as enabled
from ....
```

Just a note, you must use the same number of columns with the same data types when using `union`.

Comment: include `'' as enabled` in the middle `select`

Comment: thanks. Now I have another issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39824218/mysql-dont-show-duplicate-result-on-select