# mysql : Don't show duplicate result on SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql

The third select show results  duplicate results of the first 2 selects.
So lets say my data set just 5 ids.
The first two statements produces ids 1,2,3 enabled = 1
The last statement I need ids 4,5 enabled = 0

But right now i'm getting ids 1,2,3,4,5 enabled = 1 PLUS ids 1,2,3,4,5 enabled = 0

```
SELECT p.*, 1 as enabled
    FROM member_permissions mp
    JOIN permissions p ON p.permission_id = mp.permission_id
    WHERE member_id = 1
UNION
    SELECT pgp.*, 1 as enabled
    FROM member_permissions mp
    JOIN permission_link pl ON pl.permission_group_id = mp.permission_group_id
    JOIN permissions pgp ON pgp.permission_id = pl.permission_id
    WHERE member_id = 1
UNION
    SELECT *, 0 as enabled
    FROM permissions p
```

Comment: I cannot see the point of the final UNION/SELECT. It is bound to produce exactly the output you are complaining about.

Comment: GROUP BY is what you're looking for...

Comment: The point of the final select is to produce the remaining data that was not shown from the first 2 selects. What should I do then to produce the remaining data that I need?

Comment: @robWood Where would I put GROUP BY?

Comment: Offhand, I think you might could just stick one at the end, but you might need to wrap this in another query and group by the results of that.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7640396/removing-duplicate-results-while-using-union-select

Comment: Hmph. Are you SURE you're getting dupes without the ALL keyword? "The default behavior for UNION is that duplicate rows are removed from the result." http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html

Comment: Try it without any `p.*` / `pgp.*`. `UNION` queries should be very specific about the column order

Comment: I don't think this IS duplicates. Looks like bad join logic.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you have to do the two top queries twice to remove them from the lower query:

```
SELECT p.*, 1 as enabled
    FROM member_permissions mp
    JOIN permissions p ON p.permission_id = mp.permission_id
    WHERE member_id = 1
UNION
    SELECT pgp.*, 1 as enabled
    FROM member_permissions mp
    JOIN permission_link pl ON pl.permission_group_id = mp.permission_group_id
    JOIN permissions pgp ON pgp.permission_id = pl.permission_id
    WHERE member_id = 1
UNION
    SELECT *, 0 as enabled
    FROM permissions p where p.permission_id not in (
      SELECT p.permission_id
          FROM member_permissions mp
          JOIN permissions p ON p.permission_id = mp.permission_id
          WHERE member_id = 1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT pgp.permission_id
          FROM member_permissions mp
          JOIN permission_link pl ON pl.permission_group_id = mp.permission_group_id
          JOIN permissions pgp ON pgp.permission_id = pl.permission_id
          WHERE member_id = 1
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try using left join in that case.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       prm.*,
       CASE
         WHEN mp.member_id IS NULL OR mp2.member_id IS NULL THEN 0
         ELSE 1
       END AS ENABLED
  FROM permissions prm
  LEFT JOIN member_permissions mp
         ON mp.permission_id = prm.permission_id
        AND mp.member_id = 1
  LEFT JOIN permission_link pl
         ON pl.permission_group_id = prm.permission_group_id
  LEFT JOIN member_permissions mp2
         ON mp2.permission_group_id = pl.permission_group_id
        AND mp2.member_id = 1
```

Not a best solution as I think, but it may work